# If you don't add parameters to firebase analytics console, will the parameters get stored?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

Since there is a limit of how many parameter you can add for each app, can I just pass those parameters but not add the parameter to the console (so that in the future I can use BigQuery to export all the raw data back out if needed)?

Answer (score 2):

The parameters are stored no matter you track them or not. If you don't track the parameters, you can still access them via BigQuery.